# How to count the occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: javascript, html

The following code create a web page form. It asks a user to enter a character in an input box, then a sentence in an another box. Then the user should be able to click in a button to count the number of times the character appeared in the sentence entered in the second input box. The sentence should include only letters .  The problem I am having is that I am having an error message saying that I entered non alphabets in the box, although i enter only characters!

Any idea why this is happening please !

Here is my HTML / javascript code:

```js
//<![DATA[
'use strict';

function updateForm(id) {

  var letter = "";
  var sentence = "";
  var occurencies = 0;
  var form = document.getElementById(id);

  letter = form.box1.value;
  sentence = form.box2.value;

  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++)

    if (sentence.charAt(i) == letter)
      occurencies++;

  form.box3.value = occurencies;

}


function isAlphabet(elem, helperMsg) {
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (elem.value.match(alphaExp)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert(helperMsg);
      elem.focus();
      return false;
    }
  } //-->
```

```css
body {

  background-color: lightblue;

}

form {

  width: 500px;

  margin: 0 auto;

}

h4 {

  font-family: sans-serif;

  font-size: xx-large;

  text-align: center;

}

h1,

h2,

h3 {

  font-family: sans-serif;

  font-style: italic;

  font-size: large;

  text-align: center;

}

input[type="text"] {

  width: 100%;

  padding: 12px 20px;

  margin: 8px 0;

  box-sizing: border-box;

  font-style: italic;

}

input[type="button"] {

  background: #B9DFFF;

  color: #fff;

  border: 10px solid #eee;

  border-radius: 30px;

  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #eee;

  position: absolute;

  left: auto;

}

input[type="button"]:hover {

  background: #016ABC;

  color: #fff;

  border: 5px solid #eee;

  border-radius: 30px;

  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #eee;

}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="boxes">

  Box 1:
  <input type="text" name="box1" value="" placeholder="Enter a single 
         letter" maxlength="1" />
  <li class="rq">Only alphabet letters are allowed.</li>
  <br />Box 2:
  <input type="text" name="box2" value="" placeholder="Enter a sentence" />

  <br />Result:
  <input type="text" id="letters" name="box3" readonly />
  <br />
  <input type="button" name="update" value="Update" onclick="isAlphabet(document.getElementById('letters'), 'Only Letters are allowed')" />

</form>
```

Comment: You're doing the is Alphabet on the output field, while you want to do it on the field where the sentence is filled in.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the wrong form field:

```
onclick="isAlphabet(document.getElementById('letters')...
```

As I understand you want to check box1 not 'box3/letters'...

Add id='box1' to that input element and then check like this:

```
onclick="isAlphabet(document.getElementById('box1')...
```

Comment: `You are checking the wrong form field:` Good observation

Answer (score 1):

You code seems to be fine, just try and trim the element value before you match the same

```
if (elem.value.trim().match(alphaExp)) {
  return true;
}
```

ensure that you are passing right value to this `isAlphabet` function

```
<input type="button" name="update" value="Update" onclick="isAlphabet(document.getElementById('box1'), 'Only Letters are allowed')" />
```

to count the number of occurences

```
 letter = form.box1.value;
 sentence = form.box2.value;
 var occurences = sentence.split( letter ).length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the `isAlphabet` function is called in this code. And it checks an empty field. Your `onclick` attribute is addressed to that element.

```
onclick="isAlphabet(document.getElementById('letters'), 'Only Letters are allowed')"
```

It is holding an empty string when the `isAlphabet` function is called. An empty string is non-alphanumeric so it returns false.

As robert mentions, you need to include a reference to box1 or box2 in your call to isAlphabet as this is it's input. That is if you need to call it at all.

Also, I can't see a call to you main `updateForm` function anywhere. Unless this is not the full code, you need to include that. For example, you could do...

```
<input type="button" name="update" value="Update" onclick="isAlphabet(getElementById('box1, box2'))" />
```

with those parameters passed to the function.

Because they are passed to the function you don't need to declare them, they are right there for you to use.

You can also just include the validation within this function. To alert if it's non alphabetic.

```
function updateForm(letter, sentence) {

  var occurences = 0;
  var form = document.getElementById(id);

  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if (sentence.charAt(i) == letter) {
      occurences++;
    }
  }
  if(letter.match(alphaExp) && sentence.match(alphaExp)) {
    ..do  the thing..
  } else {
    alert('Only Letters are allowed');
  }
}
```